# Angular material table drag and drop columns doesn't update rows

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material2, angular-material-table

Is there a way to update an Angular Material table's datasource (rows) according to the changes that have been made by drag and drop on the columns?

I have a `dropListedDrop` event which updates columns:

```js
dropListDropped(event: CdkDropList, index: number) {
  if (event) {
    moveItemInArray(this.headers, this.previousIndex, index);
    this.setDisplayedColumns();
  }
}
```

But the data in dataSource isn't being changed automatically after the drag and drop action completes.

Example here: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-drag-col?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dropListDropped(event: CdkDropList, index: number) {
  if (event) {
    moveItemInArray(this.headers, this.previousIndex, index);
    this.headers = [...this.headers];
  }
}
```

demo online [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-drag-col-lexoqy) (this solution works even if you have a Angular pipe filter)

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It mentioned [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data) that Angular Material table does not update automatically in order to optimize performance.  To Update the table you simply call `renderRows()` on the table.

You can access the table like this   `@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;`
and then called `table.renderRows();`

Comment: Good point, but cannot access the table using ViewChild; `Cannot read property 'renderRows' of undefined` [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-drag-col?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)